# SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class

Tags: rest, jax-rs, ibm-cloud

I have a **JEE rest app** for consume and build web service. When I use url of app in ibm bluemix I have an error in local server **webSphere** and also in **Bluemix**:

```
SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class

'tn.hunterViews.services.OfferService.afficherOffer:31'
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at tn.hunterViews.services.OfferService.afficherOffer(OfferService.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs20.server.LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.performInvocation(LibertyJaxRsServerFactoryBean.java:674)
at [internal classes]
```

OffersService.java

```
package tn.hunterViews.services;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import tn.hunterViews.business.OfferBusiness;
import tn.hunterViews.business.OfferBusinessRemote;
import tn.hunterViews.domain.Offer;

@Path("/Offers")
public class OfferService {

    @EJB 
    OfferBusinessRemote ofR;

    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response afficherOffer(){
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(ofR.getOffer()).build();
    }       
}
```

offersBuissness.java

```
package tn.hunterViews.business;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import tn.hunterViews.domain.Offer;
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class OfferBusiness
 */
@Stateless
public class OfferBusiness implements OfferBusinessRemote {

    @Override
    public List<Offer> getOffer() {

        Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = cl.target("https://pihunterviewsdotnet.mybluemix.net/api");
        WebTarget off = target.path("offerApi");
        List<Offer> offers = off.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<Offer>>(){}) ;
        cl.close();
        return offers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean createOffer(Offer offer) {
         Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget target = cl.target("https://pihunterviewsdotnet.mybluemix.net/api");
        WebTarget off = target.path("offerApi");
        Response resp=target.request().post(Entity.entity(offer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        if(resp.getStatus()!=201)
        return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateOffer(int id, Offer offer) {
        if (id+""!=null && id!=0 && offer.getId()!=0)
        {
            Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
             WebTarget target = cl.target("https://pihunterviewsdotnet.mybluemix.net/api/offerApi"+ id);
            target.request().build("PUT", Entity.entity(offer, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .invoke();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteOffer(int id)  {
        if (id+""!=null && id!=0)
        {
        Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
         WebTarget target = cl.target("https://pihunterviewsdotnet.mybluemix.net/api/offerApi"+ id);
        target.request().delete();
        return true;}
        return false;
    }    

    @Override
    public Offer findOfferById(int id) {
        Client cl = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget baseUrl = cl.target("https://pihunterviewsdotnet.mybluemix.net/api/offerApi");
        WebTarget getPostURL=baseUrl.path(""+id);
        Response response = getPostURL.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        Offer offer=response.readEntity(Offer.class);
        response.close();
        cl.close();
        return offer;
    }       
}
```

Please help me with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: `ofR` seems to be `null` on the line in the exception. Is there a reason you expect it not to be?

Answer (score 0):

> If the @EJB annotation cannot be resolved to an EJB, then you would
>   have received a failure when the server created an instance of the
>   class containing the @EJB annotation. Since that does not appear to be
>   happening for you, and instead the instance is created fine, just
>   without that field being set, then the server is not scanning your
>   class for annotations or you have the javax.ejb.EJB annotation class
>   packaged as part of your application.
>
> I would recommend checking the following:
>
> - Make sure the javax.ejb.EJB class is not being packaged as part of your annotation
> - Check that the web.xml for your WAR module has a version > 2.4. WAR modules with a version of 2.4 (or earlier) will not be scanned for annotations.
> - Check that the web.xml does not contain the setting metadata-complete="true". This setting turns off annotation scanning.
>
> *Source*: http://www.developersite.org/102-95523-websphere-liberty